# Best way to redirect in HTML / JS

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am currently having a problem with a redirect page.
My service needs to redirect to a different specific site for each user. I used php and everything went right.
Since I wanted to add a JS tracker I have to pass the users through an HTML page with JS.
The problem is that most users never get to the end page. 
Can someone please tell me what's wrong with my page?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
        //Tracker Code
        tracker('init', '123456789');
    </script>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0.5; url={{ $url }}" />
</head>
<body>
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        location.href = "{{ $url }}";
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, we can’t, because you did not show the actual final HTML code. But can’t you simply do this tracking on the page the user lands on?

Comment: No we can't do this, the user pass through our service only for the redirection.

Comment: If the URL is an HTTPS that can be a problem or not ?
The customer who encountered problems with the service had a site in https

Comment: Redirecting from a secure site to an insecure one could get blocked by the browser. _“No we can't do this, the user pass through our service only for the redirection.”_ - so what actual service are you providing to the user then?

Comment: The goal of the service is not pertiant to resolve the problem.
And in this case the redirection look like this. (Non-https to https)